# How to hide an inherited control in vb.net at design time?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, inheritance

I have a form A in VB.net which inherits another form B. There are 8 controls in Form B, out of which only 4 controls are required in Form A. But in Form A, all the 8 controls are visible in designer view. Their Visible property is set to false which makes them invisible at run time. But I dont want to see them on the form in design view also. Is there any way of doing it ?

Comment: WinForms or ASP.NET or ...?

Comment: If you don't want to see the controls in run time nor design time, is it worth it to have those controls anyway ?

Comment: @Visual Vincent - Winforms

Comment: @SuperPeanut - Those controls are present in Parent Form. I cannot delete them from child form, otherwise they'll cause issue in Parent Form

Comment: You'd probably have to post screenshots and explain a bit further. As it stands I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a form actually contains some controls, making them invisible in the designer is poor practice and potentially dangerous. Form A becomes heavier for no reason (those controls still get loaded!), and if there's any problems in Form B's unique controls, you could start encountering weird behaviour in Form A that you can't figure out unless you magically know to look in the document outline for the "hidden" controls.

The correct thing to do is to **create a Form C containing only the 4 shared controls** (plus whatever code they need), then have both Form A and Form B inherit from it.

Comment: Though I could not use this solution, because it will affect many forms, but this is the the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

In PageLoad event , you can set visibility of  remaining controls that you dnt need in Form A.

Comment: PageLoad event will handle the runtime issue not design time issue...right?

Comment: Yup , you are right. Just change the  access modifiers of the control to Protected(those controls you do not want) and inherit a class from child class.
Take a reference from this  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5254/Everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-Forms-Inherita

Answer (score 0):

In design mode,If your controls are overlap each other you can manage hide and showing controls with <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on controls and select **Send to Back** or **Bring to Front**

Comment: Thanks Mohsen...that helped.